# Stripe client-reference-id does not persist on Stripe Panel when using pricing table

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm sending stripe pricing plan as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stripe test</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>We offer plans that help any business!</h1>



<script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script>
<stripe-pricing-table pricing-table-id="prctbl_1Lzz3iIG2cLiTx0jaBzzuu2n"
publishable-key="pk_test_51LzyrVIG2cLiTx0jTtSPJW5Iakij92jHOLV3yoFEXd0HkoFimTDJHGxk1CaF6rkqrFLjQqCqlAq3qFHrdVHqnZYQ00f4U3vt1U"
client-reference-id="cus_Mjrmqd6bfD8gA9">
</stripe-pricing-table>

</body>
</html>
```

We can see that client-reference-id is actually `cus_Mjrmqd6bfD8gA9`; but on the stripe panel it shows up as something entirely different as in the image below which is `cus_Mjs18ntyjh4qKA`:

[image]

This is a weird behavior and I followed everything that the documentation said. Have I missed something in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pricing table will always create a brand new customer object. So the dashboard screenshot you shared shows the new customer ID created.

If you want to find the `client-reference-id` you passed, it will be in the Checkout Session object, as mentioned [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#handle-fulfillment-with-the-stripe-api).

> When the property is set, the pricing table passes it to the Checkout Session’s `client_reference_id` attribute to help you reconcile the Checkout Session with your internal system.

Comment: I have done this, but the `checkout.session.completed` event shows a null `client_reference_id`. Baffled as to why.

Comment: If you set `client_reference_id` when creating the Checkout Session, then you should see it in the `checkout.session.completed` payload. If that's not the case, I would recommend to contact [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/) with the exact Checkout Session ID that has this issue, and they should be able to help.

Comment: Thanks. It was a goofy caching issue when rebuilding my server it just wasn't picking up the latest changes. It's all fine.